# After a button is pressed to start a setInterval(), how do I clearInterval once a condition is met

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, setinterval, clearinterval

I have an app that starts an interval when a button is pressed.
I want to stop the interval after a state reaches 5.
I have tried adding the if condition in `UseEffect`, and tried putting the condition within the function itself, but both don't seem to work. The `console.log(sequence)` does print successfully in `useEffect` I can see that the sequence does indeed increase, but it keeps increasing beyond 5 and never `clearInterval`.

```
  const [sequence, setSequence] = useState(0)
    
    const interval = () =>{
        setInterval(() => {
            setSequence((prevSequence) => (
                prevSequence+1
            ))
        }, 2000);
    }

    const plant = ()=>{
        interval()
        console.log(sequence)
        if(sequence>5){
           clearInterval (interval)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(sequence)
        if(sequence>5){
            return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, [sequence]);

 return(
    <View style = {styles.container} >
        <Image
            style={{height:500,width:300,}}
            source= {tomato[sequence]}
        />
        <Button 
        title = 'Fertilize Plant' 
        style= {styles.text}
        onPress= {plant}>
        </Button>

    </View>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are not clearing the interval correctly.

```
const interval = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    setSequence((prevSequence) =>  prevSequence + 1)
  }, 2000);
};
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(sequence);
  if (sequence > 5) {
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, [sequence]);
```

Here `interval` is a reference to the function, ***not*** the actual interval timer id returned from `setInterval`.

## Solution

Store the interval timer id in a React ref to be referenced around the component.

```
const intervalRef = useRef();

const interval = () => {
  intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
    setSequence((prevSequence) =>  prevSequence + 1)
  }, 2000);
};
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalId = intervalRef.current;

  // also clear on component unmount
  return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (sequence > 5) {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }
}, [sequence]);
```

Also, there's no need to check the `sequence` value and clear the interval in the `plant` callback, the `useEffect` hook with dependency on `sequence` will handle that. `Plant` only needs to start the interval.

```
const plant = () => {
  interval();
};
```

Comment: MANY THANKS!!!  I definitely need to read up on useRef :/  No idea I had to use that

Comment: @ArîstonGiltedged I don't think there's a *requirement* to use the `useRef` hook, but it certainly makes it easy, and is a pretty React way to handle it.

Comment: Hey @Drew many thanks again for the solution and more improvements. I think my biggest problem is the lack of knowledge on timer id. Your solution is currently the only way I know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clearInterval` function to stop the interval you had set.

Here is an example;

```js
let counter = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  counter++;

  console.log(`Counter = ${counter}`);

  if (counter >= 3) {
    console.log("Interval Stopped");
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I just tried that and the clearInterval doesn't occur, not even the console.log("interval stopped") I've tried adding the `clearInterval` function in the const interval function of my code. There is also a `clearInterval` function in my useEffect, and the const plant function also has a clearInterval... but it still doesn't clear